# empty pages on pagination with meta query

Tags: pagination, meta-query

I am using meta query to filter posts by various meta tags, showing 9 posts/page, but on pagination there are as many pages as were all the posts displayed without filtering, only that empty pages are shown where the posts are filtered out.

this is my loop, it is in home.php

```
<?php

$prop_args = array (
    'posts_per_page'=> 9,
    'paged'     => $paged,
    'meta_query'    => array(   
    )
);

if (!empty($camere)) { $prop_args['meta_query'][] = array('key' => 'rooms', 'value' => $camere, 'compare' => '=' ); }
if (!empty($etaj)) { $prop_args['meta_query'][] = array('key' => 'floor', 'value' => $etaj, 'compare' => '=' ); }

$prop_qerry =  new WP_Query ( $prop_args );

if ( $prop_qerry -> have_posts()) {
    while ( $prop_qerry -> have_posts()) {
        $prop_qerry -> the_post(); 
        ?>
        <div class = "property-item">           
        <div class = "prop-list-title"> <?php the_title(); ?> </div>
        <?php get_first_image(); ?>
        <div class = "price"><?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'price', true ); ?></div>
        <div class = "excerpt-list"> 
            <?php 
            $postid = get_the_ID();
            $excerpt = get_post_meta( $postid, 'surface_useable', true ) . " mp, " .get_post_meta( $postid, 'rooms', true ) . " camere, et " . get_post_meta( $postid, 'floor', true ) . ", zona " . get_post_meta( $postid, 'zone', true ); ?> 
            <?php echo $excerpt ?>
        </div> <!-- .excerpt-list -->
        </div> <!-- .property-item -->
        <?php
    }

}

?>
<div class="navigation"><p><?php posts_nav_link(); ?></p></div>
```

Comment: please post your code

Comment: if I just override the main query with: query_posts( $prop_args ); than it`s ok